# Getting msbuild to use MT_StaticRelease

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, llvm, static-linking

How do you get msbuild to use MT_StaticRelease?

The package I'm trying to build is LLVM 3.5.1 using Visual Studio 12 64-bit on Windows 7, and the closest I've come to what seems like it should be the right command line is

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:RuntimeLibrary=MT_StaticRelease ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

but attempting to compile a test program against the LLVM libraries gets error messages like

```
LLVMSupport.lib(CommandLine.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main-0b0089.obj
```

which suggests msbuild is still using `/MD` instead of `/MT` and eyeballing the build process seems to confirm that. Is there some command line option I'm missing?

Comment: You are linking a .lib that was built with /MD.  So you need to rebuild that lib or use /MD for your main project.  The latter is *very* often the correct choice, /MT usually only works for very simple programs that have no DLL dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how to rebuild the lib and make msbuild use /MT. My program has no DLL dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure this in LLVM's CMake configuration:

```
 LLVM_USE_CRT_DEBUG=MTd
 LLVM_USE_CRT_RELEASE=MT
```